# Plagiarized answer flagged as spam

Tags: discussion

I legitimately failed a [LQP review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16502196) audit because I neglected to notice that the answer consisted 99% of text ripped from an external source, with a link to the original source. I don't dispute the failure, but rather the reason given.

> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. **You didn't pass.** This post has severe quality issues. It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful. Please **delete** or **recommend deletion** when reviewing such posts.

There's nothing nonsensical (it actually answers the question nicely), noisy, spammy, or off-topic about the answer, and it doesn't seem abusive or offensive or repulsive, unless you're the original author of the blog post whose work was ripped off with only a puny link for attribution.

What it **probably** suffers from is plagiarism. I saw on [a different review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14843211) that we do have a plagiarism reason for closure, but only for tag edits.

> This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something useful to this community specifically, and be sure to attribute the original author. See: How to reference material written by others.

I can see any of three resolutions:

- I think the answer in the LQP review should be flagged as plagiarism rather than spam. It's already closed, so I don't know whether that's even possible.
- Maybe if we just add "plagiarized" to the litany of offenses ("abusive nonsense, noise, ...") it would be less jarring.
- Do we need a "plagiarism" choice under the normal Flag workflow? Does this happen often enough to need its own flag other than the catchall mod flag? Does such a flag exist already outside the review queue and I've missed it?

Comment: *thus why so many people do not care if the review button is an incomprehensible icon or text link, they never click it anymore.*

Comment: Considering Brad's answer this was not a simple review, shrug it off and keep up the good work.

Comment: This one seems like an audit corner-case that all of us would fail, that happens, don't worry about it. Yes they probably need to change the boilerplate to *" It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic, **plagiarism** or otherwise irredeemable"*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That actually was spam. If you hover over the link, it goes to a place called `data-flair.training`, which is an ad-plastered site for commercial training services. They just copied their post from that site into an answer here, with a link, to make it look like this wasn't spam.

You don't have this context, but they posted the same link in the same way across 11 answers. These were flagged as spam and deleted.

It technically isn't plagiarism, because they wrote the original article on this commercial training site, but they posted it without any disclaimers and definitely ran afoul of our self-promotion guidelines.

Is that obvious from the audit? I don't know, but I'm pretty paranoid about links going to places like `data-flair.training`, `infotrainings.com`, etc.

Comment: I can haz "trainings"? Consider me sold! /s